# How to initialize FirebaseApp in Android app?

Tags: android

Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm.MainActivity}:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

android I'm using an official project called "messaging-app". But the prompt requires FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first, but I can't find such a method at all, and there is still a problem with the official demo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpAi8.png)

This official project "messaging-app", just 3 files, the text cannot find the API of FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)

Comment: Simply use FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) replace context with this in case of activity and requireContext() in case of fragment at the start of onCreate method